# RewriteCond on .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, api, rest

I'm writing a RESTful API for my web service.
I want all the calls of the following pattern trigger a php file that is that is located in /myserver/api/controller.php
The pattern is :
http:/www.mydomain.com/api/user
http:/www.mydomain.com/api/resource

Basically, all the calls for http://www.mydomain.com/api/* should trigger /api/controller.php

Currently, my .htaccess is in /api and looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . controller.php
```

UPDATE 1:
The .htaccess in the parent directory is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !:9000$
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:9000/$1 [P,L]
RedirectMatch 301 /jobs$ http://someurl
RedirectMatch 301 /support/$ http://someurl
RedirectMatch 301 /jobs$ http://someurl
RedirectMatch 301 /someurlA http://someurlB
```

How should I write the .htaccess file?

Thanks!

Comment: It won't work... it shows 404 for www.mydomain.com/api/user/123 for example.

Comment: Maybe you have AllowOverride None in httpd.conf? Turn on logging there with RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel to see what's going on.

Comment: Yeah, most probably this is the case.

Comment: No, I checked. It reads the .htaccess file.

Comment: @Sharon, your profile shows that so far you have received 12 answers to 7 questions and haven't yet accepted any of them. You should do something about that or you're likely to find yourself being ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.* controller.php [L]
```

Update:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.* controller.php [L]
```

Comment: I tried this but it still shows 404 instead of controller.php  Have another idea?

Comment: Are you sure .htaccess is active?

Comment: What do you mean "Active"? How can I check if it's active and change it if it's not?

Comment: Well, just add another line containing only "1", save it and hit refresh. If there is no error -- it's inactive.

Comment: If you tried my example, there was an error. I put unneeded api subdirectory. Please, try fixed version.

Comment: I tried it again and then typed www.domain.com/api/resource/ and got 404. I can't see what I'm doing wrong... The .htaccess file is in my /api folder. Do I need to add an absolute path?

Comment: Gee... It seems that Artefacto was right. Turn on logging there with RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This would redirect a request like `/api/user/5` to `/api/controller.php?q=user/5`.  The ''QSA'' will also preserve any query string variables that are already present.

Comment: He's asking only for urls that start with api/*. You're having them all.

Comment: @akond, he said his .htaccess file was already in the api directory, so it would only be effective for that directory (and any subdirectories)

Comment: This solves nothing. He already can access the requested path through `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. And you should escape the backreference. Of course, the OP says nothing about what the problem actually is.

Comment: @Artefacto, you're right, I had misread the original .htaccess - it should work as written.  However, my method at least decouples controller.php from the directory in which it resides.  And I'm not sure what you mean about escaping the backreference - $1 is the proper way to write a backreference in a RewriteRule.

Comment: @Brian Please see under http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule , flag `B`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear that Apache is even reading your .htaccess file at all. Try putting the `Wooga` non-directive in there and see if you get a 500 error.

Also, don't use .htaccess files for mod_rewrite (or anything else, for that matter) unless you have no other choice.

**UPDATE 1**

Ok, so your .htaccess file is being read. The next step is to try a simpler rule. Something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ http://httpd.apache.org/
```

If that works, then you know mod_rewrite is operating and the problem is with the matching in your rules.

**UPDATE 2**

So mod_rewrite is working, meaning that your rules are not matching. Try removing the conditions but leaving the rule as it is.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule . controller.php
```

If that causes a loop, change it to this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !controller.php controller.php
```

Comment: Also, it would help if you told us what URLs you're trying to access.

Comment: @noodl, I put it in the .htaccess in directed me. I guess the rule is wrong. Have any idea?

Comment: So you're back to where you started. I suspect that the rewrite is working but that controller.php isn't where your rules indicate it should be. Either that, or there's a .htaccess file in a parent directory that's altering the final destination after your rules have run.

Comment: Check my update. I put the .htaccess in the parent directory. Can you see any conflicts?

Comment: What happens when you request /api/controller.php directly? And no, I can't see any conflicts, although your [P] proxy directive is a little suspicious..

Comment: Ok, try adding RewriteBase /api/ to the .htaccess file in /api/

Comment: This is exactly what @akond suggested. Now it works. Thanks a lot!